# Y- axis static in a moving bar graph jqplot

Tags: html, jqplot

I have a plot using jqplot in which since there are too many data i have to make the graph scrollable to left and right .I dont want my Y- axis and legend to move with the graph.I want them to be static and only the graph to move .please help!